# Dynamic export in Typescript module

Tags: typescript, yaml, config

I would like to import properties from YAML field using this syntax:

```
import { DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_PORT} from 'my-config.yml';
```

Behind the scenes I have code that would parse YML and pass correct values needed, so that part is not a problem.

However, I am not sure how to declare module in `typings.d.ts` to support this kind of syntax. I have tried it doing this way:

```
declare module '*.yml' {
    const content: any;
    export = content;
}
```

It would allow this syntax, which is not ideal:

```
import config from 'my-config.yml';
console.log(config.DATABASE_HOST);
```

Also tried this, however did not work as well:

```
declare module '*.yml' {
    const content: any;
    export = content;
}
```

Another thing I have tried, but this totally disabled type checking. I would like to at least be able to define config field type.

```
declare module '*.yml'
```

In ts config I have enabled both `esModuleInterop` and `allowSyntheticDefaultImports`.

I have mentioned that at top, but want to clarify again that I do not have problem with importing YAML into TS/JS context, problem is just with typing it out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend an alternative approach. You can generate one ts file per yml file in same folder like following...

Lets say you can generate a file called `my-config.ts` (remember it is ts, not d.ts)

```js
import c from './my-config.yml';

export interface IMyConfig {
    DATABASE_HOST: string,
    DATABASE_POR: number
}

const myConfig: IMyConfig = c;

export default myConfig;
```

You can use gulp or grunt to generate these additional ts files by looking at the yml file.

Usage

```js
// this will load .ts
// which in turn will load the .yml
import myConfig from "my-config";

// you will get intellisense here...
```

Either this or you can write a typescript language service plugin to provide declarations, but it is really time consuming, generating ts files is much simpler option.

Here is more information about language service plugin, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin

Plugin is not great idea for small one time usage, as future version of typescript may break the plugin, but your generated ts files will work with future version and you can easily change your script to make some modifications.

Comment: That is a good option I have considered it, however there will be very large amount of YML files, so running generation each time is not very convenient, so that is why I am trying to find wildcard solution.

Comment: @arminas You can write plugin, but it is no very convenient, your generator can probably use last modified to check if file is modified and it can skip generation if it was already generated. It has to be done only once.

Comment: Another problem with generation is additional step, if you have 10 developers working on system, they have to regenerate definitions each time they pull and each time they add new entry.
Or if it's commited into git, then you end up with 2 versions (YML and TS) of same data in repo, you might end up with merge conflicts and other issues.
I would sacrifice strong typing to not have these problems and just have that module export `any`, however it seems that it's not that simple.

Comment: You can have file extension as .yml.ts and you can ignore a file pattern for example, *.yml.ts so all generated files will not be committed. This way you can avoid merge conflicts. 

Pre build step can verify and generate the new/modified files. This is exactly how sass web pack etc work. 

Plugin is better alternative in that case, but yes it requires maintenance. Debugging plug-in will be tricky.

Comment: Yes not committing these definitions is an option, but in my case it would be hard to maintain, and having another step for generation would really slow things down. 
As for plugin, I have read that it will not solve TS typing errors, it just helper for autocompletion, etc. so I think it will also not solve my issue.